# Forcing Facebook Comment Plugin locale

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm reading a lot of answers, and none seems to work and since a lot of thoses answers are 3 to 4+ years old, here I ask...

How can someone force the Facebook Comment Plugin locale?

Right now, I have two locale to my site, "fr_CA" and "en_US". Depending on which we visite, I include Facebook's javascript SDK like so:

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/[LOCALE_INSERTED_HERE]/all.js";`

But it doesn't seems to do the trick as I am getting reports that on the "fr_CA" included SDK the comment plugin is showing in english.

Personnally, I'm getting mixed results, as on the french page it seems to be included most of the time in english, but some rare times it loads in French. I've tried different browser language, changing the language of my Facebook account, nothing seems to work.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: How much effect specifying a language for the social plugins has eventually, depends of course on the quality of translation Facebook has available to begin with. If a word/phrase is not translated into that language yet, then most likely the English version will show, as a fallback. I noticed you are using fr_CA – have you tried fr_FR instead? I assume that could have a better chance of being “complete.”

Comment: @CBroe I'll give it a show today. However, I do see the plugin popping up in french from time to time, if it was a translation case, wouldn't it always be en ?

Comment: Not if the amount of translated phrases for fr_FR and fr_CA differs. Facebook relies in large parts on its user base for their translations into other languages – maybe there haven’t been so many French-speaking Canadians yet that participated?